# Making a "library" project read only in a solution

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, solution

I have a solution with some projects in that make up a library. I use this library in some of my other solutions. I do this by making a reference to the dll which is generated when the library solution is compiled. So far, so good.

Now I'm debugging one of those "other solutions". I see that I'm using a function from the library I built and I want to see what the code does. I hit F12 and I'm taken to a very useless page where I see only the signature.

I could add the library projects to my solution. this is unsatisfactory because when someone is editing the solution I want it to be clear that the messing about with the library bit is going to affect other programs. If I can describe my desire crudely, I would say I want the library solution to be show when I hit F12, but be read only.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the complied option of the library. If the library is built without debug symbols, it would not be possible to debug inside in a `normal` human readable way. I suggest you compile/build the library with debug option. That may solve your problem.
HTH!

Comment: I have the library's code on my computer and I want to be able to step through it as I debug my other solution but I don't want the library files to be editable. I only want to be able to edit the library if I specifically open the library solution file in VS.